# .class a:hover vs .class:hover a

Tags: css, hover

Couldn't find an answer to something I've been wondering about.

Is there a difference between `.class2 a:hover {}` and `.class2:hover a {}`? Or a preference for one over the other?

I've been using `.class2 a:hover {}` to alter anchors on anchor hover (ie: anchor text color), but when I wanted to alter the div that held the anchor as well (ie: anchor color and div background-color both change on hover), I had to use `.class2:hover a {}` for it to work. In doing so, I got confused as to the difference because between the two as they are written so similarly.

Thanks!

**EDIT**
Edited the question to be more clear. Thanks for untwisting my brain :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My understanding is this:

`.class2 a:hover` will target any hyperlink tags within `.class2` elements when the `a` tags are hovered.

`.class2:hover a` will target any hyperlink `a` tags within `.class2` elements when `.class2` is hovered.

The distinction is which element you hover in order to change those styling rules.

Example:

```css
.box{
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.case1 a:hover {
  background: blue;
}  

.case2:hover a {
   background: green;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="box case1"><a href="#">case 1</a></div>
    <div class="box case2"><a href="#">case 2</a></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In this case, do you want to hover the `.class2` element or the `a`?

Comment: I wanted to hover the `.class1` div so that it changed the color of the anchor tag that was inside it rather than just hovering the anchor because there is a `background-color` change to `.class1` on hover as well. So I had to add `.class2` to the anchor tag and write it as `.class1:hover, .class2:hover a{}` for it to work. That made me wonder about the difference.

Comment: Yes, your "case 2" example is what I did and it made me wonder about the difference :)

Comment: what is difference in `.class :hover` and `.class:hover` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
.class2 a:hover {}
```

With the above, the style would only apply to `a` when the `a` element is hovered specifically, if the `.class` element has padding or other content, hovering over the other parts of the `.class` element will **not** trigger the hovered style for `a`

---

```
.class2:hover a {}
```

While the above will trigger the hover style for `a` if any part of the `.class2` element is hovered (padding, content, etc..)

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/0jx0t90s/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is a difference.

Behaviorally, there may not seem like a difference, but if you add a margin around your `<a>` tag, you might find that your first selector (`.class2 a:hover {}`) will stop working as indended.

Answer (score 0):

`.class:hover a` selects the `a` link when any part of the `class` is hovered upon while `.class a:hover` selects the `a` link only when the `a` link is hovered upon

Answer (score 0):

In class2:hover, you're activating the CSS class under all elements nested in the class. This includes if you wanted to add padding outside the border of your links.

In class2 a:hover, the CSS class is only activated when you're hovering specifically over the link. Otherwise, the class is ignored.

Hope this helps!